# How to get around with conflict of bootstrap class names

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

We got a project which was handed to over to us by the client. In that say 38 screens are to be developed by us, the thing is they have already developed several screens before hand(more than 20) and handed over to us. The app is a **hybrid mobile app**, single page(**using angular**) and **cordova**. So the thing is they `did not use any framework like bootstrap` to develop the pages they have developed before handling it over to us. **And other thing to note is since we have to use angular, all the css files will be minified into a single file**. And `they used the class names like row in their project, which are conflicting with the names in the bootstrap`. *But desperately want to use bootstrap, is there any way that we can use bootstrap without conflicting their already developed class names, or simply put, we don't want to modify their old classes in css*, **In a single page environment**. Any  suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is one solution, `isolating Bootstrap CSS`.

The idea is editing the bootstrap LESS file, and crunching adding a class (Suppose `bootstrap-iso`) before every element and to use bootstrap wrapping around like this

```
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
  <!-- Any HTML here will be styled with Bootstrap CSS -->
</div>
```

Good news is you don't need to crunch and change : [Here is link of crunched css file](https://formden.com/static/assets/demos/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso/bootstrap-iso.css)

Get this file, link to your site and use wrapping around like above. Hope this would be helpful to you.

[Reference, Learn More](https://formden.com/blog/isolate-bootstrap)